# What is the direct translation of ゆっくりする in English?

Tags: translation

I don't know what the direct translation of ゆっくりする in English is. Do you know?

Comment: chill out, lounge and relax are the closest words in english.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ゆっくり can be translated as "slowly" or "without rushing", according to [jisho.org](http://jisho.org/word/%E3%82%86%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8A):

> #### ゆっくり
>
> 1. slowly; at ease; restful (Onomatopoeic or mimetic word)

...and [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%82%86%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8A):

> #### ゆっくり (romaji yukkuri)
>
> 1. slowly; at ease, without rushing, restfully

If you're familiar with the "Yukkuri" internet meme, you've probably also seen it translated as ["Take it easy"](http://yukkuri.wikia.com/wiki/Take_it_easy):

> #### Take it easy
>
> “Take it easy” is the Alpha and Omega of Yukkuri speech, the spoken
>   embodiement of all what a Yukkuri strives for in life. It's also
>   somewhat an untranslatable pun about the "Yukkuri" word, that's
>   japanese both for "Taking it easy", both for "Taking it slowly", thus
>   cementing the idea of Yukkuris as lazy creatures who like to enjoy a
>   slowpaced, easy life.

The [する](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B) suffix is a verb meaning "to do (something)". The [Pocket Kenkyusha Japanese Dictionary](https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=!ISBN+978-0-19-860748-9) explains that it can be used to turn the adverb ゆっくり into an intransitive verb:

> **yu「kku」ri** ゆっくり *adv.* (~ to)
>
> **1** slowly; without hurry; leisurely.
>
> ...
>
> **yukkuri suru** (~する) *vi.* take one's time; stay long.